# Update manager fails to move files from tmp

Tags: 7, installation

I've this configuration:

- Fedora Core 21 (64bit)
- vsftpd: version 3.0.2
- Drupal 7.41

I have a unix user called user1 who has home dir /home/user1
and Drupal root is at /home/user1/www

The Drupal temporary directory is at /home/user1/tmp

I'm trying to install the [Corporate Clean](https://www.drupal.org/project/corporateclean) theme using the update manager but it fails giving this message:

> corporateclean Error installing / updating File Transfer failed,
>   reason: Cannot move
>   /home/user1/tmp/update-extraction-5345b836/corporateclean/comment-wrapper.tpl.php
>   to /www/sites/all/themes/corporateclean/comment-wrapper.tpl.php

I checked ownership and permissions of `/home/user1/tmp/update-extraction-5345b836/corporateclean` and it's owned by apache and permissions are like so:

> 755
>   drwxr-xr-x 7    755 apache 4096 Dec  9 07:05 corporateclean

Is this the right permissions / user for the extracted directory by the update manager? The owner / permissions is causing the issue and not allowing the move.

Answer (score 1):

After reading [Enable FTP on your server](https://www.drupal.org/node/1608658) i applied the changes as mentioned in the `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` file.

The changes applied are

```
Linux Instructions (UNSECURED):

Step 1:  sudo  yum  install  vsftpd

Step 2:  sudo emacs /etc/vsftpd.conf
Uncomment these settings:
listen=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES

Step 3:  sudo service vsftpd restart
```

i then changed the ownership of the drupal root to apache user

`chown -R apache:apache /home/user1/www`

and this fixed the problems for me. am able to install themes via FTP method.

**Please note - the method i've used is potentially insecure. Don't use on production server.**

Thanks.

Yashesh

Comment: Your answer will be useless if link to documentation will ever change. This is considered low quality here.

Comment: am  a newbie here. thx molot for your feedback. i've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it will help you or not. Please use the following command to sure the directory owner permission.

```
ls -l
```

If you see the www-data missing then you can try the following command

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /home/user1/tmp
```

Comment: thx imran   
the directory /home/user1/tmp is owned by apache:apache.   
drwxrwxrwx 2 apache apache 4096 Dec  9 08:30 tmp